# Css absolute position and overflow:hidden don't go so well

Tags: html, css

This is my code http://jsfiddle.net/noppanit/8D7QN/

As you can already see that the text overflows out of the container, I tried putting overflow:hidden into the text already but it didn't work. I understand that because it's absolute position, so technically it's out of the container. But I'm not sure how to fix this. The text has to be on top of the image that's why I make it absolute position.

If you guys could shed some light to me, that's be awesome. I'm very new at CSS.

Comment: Fixed: http://jsfiddle.net/8D7QN/3/

Comment: What's the desired solution. you want the text to be inside that image and user scrolls within it?

Comment: I don't really want the scroll, I want to use. text-overflow: ellipsis;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set a height on the `.text_content` ([example](http://jsfiddle.net/8D7QN/1/)) or, **preferably**, set `overflow:hidden;` on `.text_image` ([example](http://jsfiddle.net/8D7QN/2/)).

Answer (score 1):

You assume that it is overflowing out of the container.  It is not.  The container has a background that is not repeated and is smaller than the container.  The container has no `height` css and thus sizes to the content.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/8D7QN/7/